# How can I make PyDev autoformat the maximum number of characters per line?

Tags: python, eclipse, formatting, pydev

I am using PyDev for Python programming in Eclipse.

Is it possible to make PyDev auto-format my code to limit the maximum number of characters on a single line?

Comment: I'm not really sure about it, but I think the auto-formatting algorithm respects the `Print margin` value set in Preferences>Editors>Text Editors . I'll test it and tell you

Comment: No, that was wrong, PyDev only does this for `import` statements (splitting it into multiline statements to respect the print margin)

Answer (score 6):

### With standard PyDev

It seems that this option is only available in Eclipse's Java Editor.

The Java editor allows you to create "profiles" for the code formatter, while PyDev's options for the code formatter are very limited.

### However,

You can hack this. `PythonTidy.py` is an awesome script that cleans up Python code to make it follow PEP8 conventions, and that can be tweaked with your own settings.

### PythonTidy (code cleanup & formatting)

Get [here](http://lacusveris.com/PythonTidy/PythonTidy-1.22.python) ([homepage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonTidy/)) the source for **PythonTidy**.

You will see inside the file, at the beginning of the code and just after the comments, that many settings are defined.

The first one of these is `COL_LIMIT` with its default value set to `72`. Now you can use **PythonTidy** to format your code the way you want.

### Integration with PyDev

Now you have to make this work with PyDev's formatting. This [blog post](http://bear330.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/using-pythontidy-in-pydev-as-code-formatter/) will explain it really better than me, but still I'll sum up the steps :

- Write a Jython interface betwenn PyDev's editor (**PyEdit**) and **PythonTidy**. This blog's author already wrote a wrapper script in the public domain available in the above link or [here](http://pastebin.com/sXDkNT84) in case the link goes 404.
- Save this file anywhere you want, with the name `pyedit_pythontidy.py`, along with the `PythonTidy.py` file.
- Configure PyDev to use this script as its *Code Formatter*. You can do this in **Preferences > PyDev > Scripting PyDev**

  - *Note #1: I really recommend reading the original [blog post](http://bear330.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/using-pythontidy-in-pydev-as-code-formatter/) to have a better understanding*
  - *Note #2: The wrapper script author did not implement **Code Block formatting**, so this means you can only format a full file. This should not be that hard to implement, up to you.*
  - *Note #3: All credits goes to [bear330](http://bear330.wordpress.com) for the **PyDev integration** part.*

Comment: I followed the steps of the blog and yours. Either it doesn't work or I don't know how to use it... How should I order the formatting of a whole file? crtl+shift+F (file selected) doesn't change a bit. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any useful information in your Eclipse Error log ? (also, check the two checkboxes related to the error log in the `Scripting PyDev` dialog)

Comment: No interesting logs at all, for now I will run the Pythontidy script without real integration in Eclipse. Thanks anyway